# Retrieve data from linked table based on bit value of record that may or may not exist

Tags: sql

i have two tables. a user table and a photo table. *IF* a user uploads photo's, they have the option of specifying *only* one as a 'primary' profile photo (enforced on the front-end).

```
tbl_users
---------
user_id
username

tbl_photos
---------
photo_id
user_id
is_primary (bit)
file_name
```

when i'm querying a list of users on a user search, for example, i want their chosen primary photo to display. however, if there are no linked records in the photo table or there are, but none are marked primary, I still want to return the users record and perhaps NULL or some other value for the file_name.

how would I accomplish this?

ps. i'm currently doing this through two separate calls to the database, but want this done in one call for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what DB you use this works (`userid2query` being the id of the user you want to retrieve):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, p.photo_id, p.file_name 
from tbl_users u
left outer join tbl_photos p on u.user_id = p.user_id and p.is_primary = 1
where u.user_id = userid2query
```

It returns the user information and the primary photo information - IF no primary photo or no photo at all it stills returns the user information but returns NULL for the photo information columns.

Comment: sorry, but I just realized if i don't filter on user id and get more than one user, every user that doesn't have a primary photo specified, get's the same value as the one who does. in other words, if there is only one record in the photo table marked as primary, every user in that result set will show that photo_id and file_name

Comment: never mind, things got a litte mucked up after I copied and pasted. All working again!

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id , photo_id from tbl_users left join tbl_photos on tbl_users .user_id=tbl_users.user_id
```